# CSS get extra two words on my button

Tags: css

I create a button with hover and active effect but after I created it come out extra "??" on my design.

```
<form id="form-login">      
   <a href="#" class="login"> Login </a>       
</form>​​
```

And this is my CSS, I did change my "#form-login" to ".form-login" as well but not working.  Please help me to check where is did wrong. It keep show me "??" on my design.

```
/* Login button */
#form-login {
/* Size and position */
    width: 340px;
    margin: 60px auto 30px;
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;
}

#form-login .login {
/* Size and position */
    width: 49%;
    height: 38px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;

/* Styles */    
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;

/* Font styles */
    font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 38px; /* Same as height */
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;

/* Background color */
    margin-right: 1%;
    background: #34a5cf; /* Fallback */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#34a5cf, #2a8ac4);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#34a5cf, #2a8ac4);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#34a5cf, #2a8ac4);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#34a5cf), to(#2a8ac4));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#34a5cf, #2a8ac4);
    background: linear-gradient(#34a5cf, #2a8ac4);
    border: 1px solid #2b8bc7;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    text-decoration: none;
}

#form-login .login:hover {
    box-shadow: 
        inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), 
        inset 0 20px 40px rgba(255,255,255,0.15);
}

#form-login .login:active{
    top: 1px;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's your CSS. Question signs `?` always smell like an unicode character display problem. Therefore the first question to ask you is: what encoding are you using in your html document output? ISO, UTF-8, …

Comment: There is absolutely no problem with the CSS shown... Try to check your source when the ? are displayed, it might help figure out what it is.

Comment: there is absolutely no problem. taking your code as it is here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YLhca/

Comment: @Salketer I have check with my source code, it doesn't contain my ?? words. Just after I done with the CSS it come out the ??

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's your CSS.

Question signs `?` always smell like an unicode character display problem.

Therefore the first thing to do is to check if you are using the correct encoding in your html document output. If it's not UTF-8, change it to UTF-8 and there's a good chance those question marks will *"magically"* turn into unicode characters instead of question marks. Just be sure to save and serve your html as UTF-8.

Hint to get you started:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>demo</title>
<style type='text/css'>
/* Login button */
#form-login
{
    /* Size and position */
    width: 340px;
    margin: 60px auto 30px;
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
#form-login .login
{
    /* Size and position */
    width: 49%;
    height: 38px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    /* Styles */
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    /* Font styles */
    font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 38px; /* Same as height */
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    /* Background color */
    margin-right: 1%;
    background: #34a5cf; /* Fallback */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#34a5cf, #2a8ac4);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#34a5cf, #2a8ac4);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#34a5cf, #2a8ac4);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#34a5cf), to(#2a8ac4));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#34a5cf, #2a8ac4);
    background: linear-gradient(#34a5cf, #2a8ac4);
    border: 1px solid #2b8bc7;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    text-decoration: none;
}
#form-login .login:hover {
    box-shadow:
    inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
    inset 0 20px 40px rgba(255,255,255,0.15);
}
#form-login .login:active{
        top: 1px;
}
</style>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form-login">
<a href="#" class="login">Login</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Copy-and-paste it into a new document, save it as *"UTF-8"*, and then open it in your browser. You'll see there are no question signs `?` (anymore).

**Please note**: I removed the useless spacing between the login text and the surrounding tag, changing `> Login <` to `>Login<`.

Comment: Even I do it on a new page it will come out the same problem.

Comment: Ya I did using <meta charset="utf-8"> on my source as well. :(

Comment: Are you saving the document as UTF-8 too? If yes, what editor are you using?